# Can I use a 3.5mm mic in an ipod touch?

Tags: audio, microphone, recording

I have a microphone with a 3.5 mm jack. Can I use this for recording in garage band in my ipod touch. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly - you need, at minimum, a plug adaptor to take the 2-way connector on the mic to the Apple standard 4-way connector.

There are a lot more advanced methods too, involving actual 'live' interfaces designed to do just that - it really depends on what kind of mic it is as to what interface would be best, though if its default connector is a 2-way mini-jack, then my guess would be it's a non-powered electret condenser, which are not always the best for music recording.

I'd consider having a look at some of the [IK Multimedia iRig](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=vocals) devices or alternatively, just start from this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iphone%20mic%20connector&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for simpler connectors